# Alternative to sum or prod for subtraction or division in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, division, series, subtraction

Is there a built in function to get either total subtract or division of a series of values?

For example:

```
s1 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
s1
a   -0.238762
b   -0.669687
c    0.618808
d    1.056264
e   -1.472528

result = 0.228405
```

I guess I should create a `lambda` function with the `subtract` or `div` methods and apply to the series, but I do not see how to apply these methods on the same series.

Comment: It's not clear from your question and `result`, what you want.

Comment: it is just a simple subtraction. First value minus the next one minus the next one and so on...Sorry

Comment: @gis20: I notice you have asked 21 questions but haven't accepted any answers. Please consider revisiting your older questions and marking the answers that helped you there as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a very direct way in pandas, but in NumPy there is the `ufunc.reduce` method to do this:

```
>>> s1
a   -0.238762
b   -0.669687
c    0.618808
d    1.056264
e   -1.472528
Name: s1, dtype: float64

>>> np.subtract.reduce(s1.values) 
0.22838100000000017
```

(Note: this is very slightly different to your expected value due to rounding - the Series only prints six decimal places.)

For division you can use `np.divide.reduce(s1.values)`.

---

If you truly had to implement this in pandas, you could write:

```
s2 = -s1[::-1]              # multiply values by -1, reverse Series
s2.iloc[-1] = -s2.iloc[-1]  # set last value back to original sign
s2.sum()                    # sum
```

Which again yields `0.2283810...`. This will probably be much slower due to the creation and indexing of the new Series `s2`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would use `reduce` with a lambda function.

```
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: a - b, s)
0.22838100000000017
```

And some other common operations:

```
reduce(lambda a, b: a * b, s)
-0.15389660387465764

s.product()
-0.15389660387465764

reduce(lambda a, b: a / float(b), s)
-0.3704259301942105

reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, s)
-0.70590500000000023

s.sum()
-0.7059050000000002
```